How to create embeddable form by Preact
I want to create a form by Preact that can be embedded anywhere in 3 types:

inline: when embedding the script anywhere in the code, the form will be displayed right there
float bubble: will appear at the position I pass in
popup: after embedding in the  of the web, this form
will appear after 3 seconds of accessing the web
What should I do?

I have created a form and I don't know how to trigger it according to the 3 types I mentioned.
import { useState } from 'preact/hooks';
import PoweredBy from './poweredBy';
import contentSetting from '../mock-data/content-widget.json'
interface RegisterFormProps {
    onClose: () => void;
}

function RegisterForm({ onClose }: RegisterFormProps) {
    const [name, setName] = useState("")
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState("")
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("")
    const handleInputName = (e) => {
        setName(e.target.value)
    }
    const handleInputPhoneNumber = (e) => {
        setPhoneNumber(e.target.value)
    }
    const handleInputEmail = (e) => {
        setEmail(e.target.value)
    }
    const onSubmit = () => {
        const bodyData = {
            name: name,
            phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
            email: email
        }
        console.log("body", bodyData)
    }
    return (
        <div className="form absolute max-w-[350px] max-h-[500px] bottom-24 right-12 border rounded-xl">
            <div className="px-4 pb-8">
                {contentSetting.businessLogo?.display && (
                    <div className="flex gap-4 h-8 items-center py-4">
                        <img src={contentSetting?.businessLogo?.value} alt="" className="h-8" />
                        <span className="font-semibold text-sm">{contentSetting?.businessName?.value}</span>
                    </div>
                )}
                <span className="pb-2 text-2xl font-semibold">{contentSetting.title}</span>
                <p className="pb-4 text-sm text-gray-400 font-normal">{contentSetting.subtitle}</p>
                {contentSetting.inputNamePlaceholder && (
                    <div className="relative mb-4">
                        <label htmlFor="name-input" className="absolute top-0 left-4 ease-in-out text-sm text-slate-500">Name</label>
                        <input name="name-input" onInput={handleInputName} className="bg-white py-4 px-4 w-full text-base rounded-xl border border-gray-400" />
                    </div>
                )}
                {contentSetting.inputPhoneNumberPlaceholder && (
                    <div className="relative mb-4">
                        <label htmlFor="phone-input" className="absolute top-0 left-4 ease-in-out text-sm text-slate-500">Phone number</label>
                        <input name="phone-input" onInput={handleInputPhoneNumber} className="bg-white py-4 px-4 w-full text-base rounded-xl border border-gray-400" />
                    </div>
                )}
                {contentSetting.inputEmailAddressPlaceholder && (
                    <div className="relative">
                        <label htmlFor="email-input" className="absolute top-0 left-4 ease-in-out text-sm text-slate-500">Email address</label>
                        <input name="email-input" onInput={handleInputEmail} className="bg-white py-4 px-4 w-full text-base rounded-xl border border-gray-400" />
                    </div>
                )}

                <div className="flex justify-end">
                    <button className="button px-4 py-3 hover:opacity-90 bg-black text-white rounded-[8px] text-base my-10" onClick={onSubmit}>{contentSetting.contentButton}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <PoweredBy />
        </div>
    )
}

export default RegisterForm;


You're going to need to clarify your 3 types. What is "will be displayed right there" supposed to mean? Where the script tag is? What is "the position I pass in" for float bubble? And how is a float bubble different from a popup?

What I want is that when I build this preact project, I get a single js file, then I will embed it in another web I want
<script src="abc.js" width="500px" height="200px " color="white" type="inline"></script>
So I want to ask how I can pass those attributes through my form

inline: if you want to embed it on any web page, in any div element, you will embed my script tag directly there

float bubble: it will always display in the position you set in our admin page, it will be included in the script tag, for example   then it will display a bubble icon in the right corner of the screen. When you click on this icon, the form will open

popup: this is an automatic open form, when you want it to show up on any page you can embed it on that page, when you access this page for 3 seconds it will automatically show up and you can turn it off to see it. You can continue surfing the page

This isn't really a question for Stack Overflow then, as you're mostly asking for someone to build your component. Each one of those carries some complexity and you're better off breaking them up into individual questions when you get stuck.
